# Particular integral for $x\sin(1-x)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y''+y=x\sin(1-x)$$

I have got that the solution to the homogenous case is
$$y =  A\sin(x)+B\cos(x),$$
but what about the inhomogenous case? Which particular integral do I use?

I have tried 
$$Cx\sin(1-x) + D\sin(1-x) + Ex\sin(1-x) + F\sin(1-x)$$ 
but it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, I've corrected the typo.

Comment: $y = \int_0^x \xi \sin(1-\xi) \sin (x-\xi) \, d\xi$  is a particular solution.

Comment: if you want to use the method of undetermined coefficients, then you will need $x^2\sin x, x^2\cos x, x\sin x, x\cos x.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try splitting up $\sin(1-x)$ using the difference formula for $\sin$ -

$$\sin(\alpha \pm \beta) = \sin \alpha \cos \beta \pm \cos \alpha \sin \beta \!$$

This should tell you what your particular solution should look like (remember that it can't be identical to, or even contain one of the homogeneous solutions).

Comment: Ok, so that gives $$\sin(1)\cos(x)-\cos(1)\sin(x).$$

So $C\cos(x)+D\sin(x)$ evidently won't work, so perhaps I need a factor of $x$ in there too?

Comment: Remember you have the $x$ multiplying as well. Normally we would guess 

$$(Ax+B)\sin x + (Cx+D)\cos x$$

however as you said, some of those are the homogenous solution. Multiply our solution by $x$ until it is sufficiently different, so 

$$(Ax^2+Bx)\sin x + (Cx^2+Dx)\cos x$$

Let us know if that helps.

Comment: Yeah, got it now, thanks :)